# Apache says MySQL daemon already running; if I stop the other daemon, Apache can't start its own

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, mysql

## What should happen:

./lampp start mysql -u root -p

--All is right and well with the world!--

## What actually happens, and in this order:

./lampp start

mysql -u root -p

[Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)]

{at this point, phpmyinfo() shows mysql as activated}

sudo service mysql start

mysql -u root -p

[Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)]

{phpmyinfo() still shows mysql as activated}

./lampp stop

mysql -u root -p

(all is right and well with the world!)

./lampp start

Another MySQL daemon is already running...

{phpmyinfo() shows mysql as deactivated}

Basically, it seems there's some conflict going with mySQL. If I have apache running, I can't run mysql, but if I have mySQL running, I can't load it in Apache. The error remains the same. Both are trying to use the same socket, and it works if Apache isn't running. Any suggestions all would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Tom,

check your my.cnf for the path to the socket file under the mysqld and client section.

```
[mysqld]
socket=/path/to/socket

[client]
socket=/path/to/socket
```

Edit:

If the [client] section doesn't exist then put it there so you don't have to manually specify the --socket=path when connecting from command line.

Comment: socket          = /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock 

there is nothing called mysql.sock in that folder, however.

Comment: When connecting try using mysql --socket=/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock -u root -p

Comment: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Tried a few times, typing my password carefully. But at least it's a different error! Any idea what I can edit so I don't have to do that manually every time?

Comment: Try without the -p maybe the password is not set yet. To not have to enter the socket path see the answer. I editted it to include the solution.

Comment: You were right about the password. Excellent. However within my.cnf, the following exists: [client]
#password       = your_password 
port            = 3306
socket          = /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock

Comment: checking phpmyinfo, I definitely get the same list of databases as I do if i SHOW databases from mysql. So everything seems right. I ust don't know why it won't path the socket correctly without my help.

Comment: Another note: just tried mysqladmin path=[pathListedAbove] -u root password [PASSWORD] and got [Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)] again. Even though I manually specified the path...